# How to render another page (not only content) in fluid

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I search a way to render a page into another page.

I have a page with `uid=186` and I want to render this on every page, so I try to render it in the layout.The page with `uid=186` got another page template and also uses another layout (the layout is just empty, I don't really need a layout for that page).

My first try was:

```
<v:content.render pageUid="186" />
```

But that renders only the content, and also only the columns that are defined in the current page template, not the ones in the page templates I use in `uid=186`.

I also tried:

```
<v:render.request action="render" controller="Page" pageUid="186" extensionName="fluidpages"/>
```

But this leads to the PHP error:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 29 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/myhost/typo3_src-6.2.9/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/Menu/MenuContentObjectFactory.php on line 50
```

As I use a page template with much columns in the page `uid=186` I would love to render the hole page as it is, and not fetch each column.

I would also be fine with a typoscript solution.

Anyone got an idea how I could archive that?

Comment: Including the HTML header, or only the HTML inside the body tag?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a separate file that render the uid=186 with page layout of uid=186

First you have to separate the header and footer or may be you can define the different sections for header and footer in one file (for ex pageObjects.html). so you can render that section whenever you want.

```
<f:render section="Header" partial="PageObjects" arguments="{_all}" />

<v:content.render pageUid="186" />

<f:render section="Footer" partial="PageObjects" optional="TRUE" arguments="{_all}" />
```

Comment: But `<v:content.render pageUid="186" />` renders only the Content Elements, not the Page Template. I created a work around for this with partials that works great for what I need. But I did not had time to create a good answer (Also the question is not very popular)